# Plot the outcome of NDSolve for a system of differential equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to plot the solution of a system of differential equations for various values of a constant in the equations. Here is what I did:

sol[a]=NDSolve[{y'[a] == ff[a, m], x'[a] == gg[a, m],x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1}, {x[a], y[a]},{a, 0, 10}][[1, All, 2]]

Here ff[a,m] and gg[a,m] are some known functions and NDSolve already spits out the correct result for a chosen m. But I want to plot the outcome for different values of m without writing this NDSolve many times with various m (since every time I have to supply the value of m).

Basically, I want to control m in the plot, for example like this:

Plot[{sol[a,m=1][[1]],sol[a,m=2][[1]]},{a,0,10}]

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: **ff[a,m] and gg[a,m] are some known functions**  you could use Manipulate and make slider for changing $m$,. But can't show you how since you did not give definitions for these functions. You can also try `ParametricNDSolve` where $m$ is the parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion of ParametricNDsolve, I am trying to adjust it to my problem now. And those functions are awfully long and messy. Could you please show how to use the Manipulate with your example of those functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you please show how to use the Manipulate with your example of
> those functions?

Well, I was hoping you provide the definitions as it is your problem. But I made some example. You can adopt it to your long functions.,

Using `ParametricNDSolve` and using $m$ values for say $1,2,3,4,5$ you could do

```
ClearAll[f, g, t, m, x, y];
f[t_, m_] := Sin[m*t]
g[t_, m_] := Cos[m*t]
ode1 = y'[t] == f[t, m]
ode2 = x'[t] == g[t, m]
ic = {x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1}
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{ode1, ode2, ic}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}, {m}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now plot the $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ solutions for different $m$

```
Table[{xSol = x[m] /. sol, ySol = y[m] /. sol}; 
 Plot[{xSol[t], ySol[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"Solutions using m=", m}]], {m, 1, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is Manipulate version for extra credit.

[image]

```
ClearAll[f, g, t, m, x, y];
f[t_, m_] := Sin[m*t];
g[t_, m_] := Cos[m*t];
ode1 = y'[t] == f[t, m];
ode2 = x'[t] == g[t, m];
ic = {x[0] == 0, y[0] == 1};

Manipulate[
 sol = NDSolve[{ode1 /. m -> m0, ode2 /. m -> m0, ic}, {x, y}, {t, 0,10}];
 Plot[{x[t] /. sol, y[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"Solutions using m=", m0}], 
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, 
  PlotLegends -> {{"x(t)", "y(t)"}}],
 {{m0, 5, "m"}, 0, 10, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {m0}
 ]
```

Comment: I am wondering how I give extra credits? I would give you all the credits in the world:) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try `Table`.
For example, emm……

```
orbit = Table[
   Last@NDSolve[{{x''[t], y''[t]} == (G0 Mjupter r)/
       Norm[r]^3, {x'[0], 
        y'[0]} == {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]} v0, {x[0], 
        y[0]} == {x0, -v0 12 days}}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 
      10^8}], {x0, -v0 12 days Cos[\[Theta]] - 
     3*^9, -v0 12 days Cos[\[Theta]] + 3*^9, 2.1*^9}];
img[date_] := 
  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{{x[t], y[t]} /. orbit}], {t, 0, date days},
   Epilog -> { Point[{x[t], y[t]} /. orbit /. t -> date days], 
     LightRed, 
     Line[{{Vjupter (date days - 12 days), 0}, {-Vjupter 12 days, 0}}],
     Point[{Vjupter (date days - 12 days), 0}]},
   PlotRange -> {{-3*^9, 3.5*3*^9}, {-2.2*3*^9, 2.2*3*^9}}, 
   Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large,
   PlotStyle -> LightGray
   ];
Manipulate[img[date], {date, 0.1, 24, 0.1}]
```

oh, there's not enough time, just make an example by a former code by me. hope i can help you.

Comment: Thanks Jiang! But when I run it your code doesn't seem to give an output